# Importing data from 11g to 10g

Tags: oracle, import, export

I had to import a table from schema of one database to a schema of another database.I created a .dmp file of the table using "exp" command transfered the file to the other machine using ftp (using binary transfer) and when I tried to import the file on the other machine using "imp" command  I faced the error that the .dmp file is corrupt(IMP-00010).Now if one of my machine is hosting Oracle 11G and the other machine to which data has to be imported is hosting 10G ,Could that be the reason of the error which I recieved.If, yes what else could I do to get my work done?

Commands used

```
  exp flstd05/flstd05@flow30 tables=cust_order_lines file=cust_order_lines_data1.dmp

  imp flmad01/flmad01@flow04 file=cust_order_lines_data1.dmp
```

Comment: export/import should be compatible between 11 and 10. Is you destination machine of a different architecture e.g. Linux X86 to HP-UX (Itanium)?

Comment: [The version of the Export utility must be equal to the version of either the source or target database, whichever is earlier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL103). It sounds like you're using the 11g `exp` and the 10g `imp`, which will give you problems. Can you use the 10g `exp` from the target system, which would create the dump file locally and avoid the FTP step too? You should consider `expdp`/`impdp` too, but the version restriction still applies.

Comment: Try with 10g client to export since you need to import on 10g. Or upgrade your destination to 11g to import.

Comment: @AlexPoole I did try using expd /impd .As we have to transfer data between two  schemas of two different instances on different machines.I recieved the error that the schema does not exist while the CREATE TABLE command was running as the command was like

Comment: @AlexPoole Create table Schema_name.Table_Name and the schema does not exist on the current instance.Any idea what could be done to get out of this.

Comment: Following is the error message                                                                                                        "            Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE

ORA-39083: Object type TABLE failed to create with error:

ORA-01918: user 'FLSTD05' does not exist

Failing sql is:

CREATE TABLE "FLSTD05"."CUST_ORDER_LINES"

Comment: @user2262977 - you need [the `REMAP_SCHEMA` option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL927) to import into a different schema than the one you exported from.